# How to send Twitter Direct Message using PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to send a Direct Message to twitter user but the result returns null. Get Followers/Friends are working. Here is the code below, Same connection works for creating friends but not for direct message.

```
<?php
session_start();

require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
$twitteruser = "BigxxxxxNews"; //user name you want to reference
$consumerkey = "xxxxxxxxxxxElK95iNHTxtc6l";
$consumersecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxEN5WBg1p6ZIuNCleoCzfsmTXXDbpNiujiBb"; 
$accesstoken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0F4o3tr1pxgGIcGC1F"; 
$accesstokensecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4XqsySwL6GKXizUSeizCryf"; 

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

 ***  Post DM to ID Start              ***
 *****************************************
 **/

    $userid= '90000000256';
    $msg = "This is my direct message"; 

$json = [
    'event' =>[
        'type' =>'message_create',
        'message_create' =>[
            'target' =>[
                'recipient_id' =>'1622222804'
            ],
            'message_data' =>[
                'text' =>'testdirectmessage123'
                ]
        ]
    ]
];
$j1=array('event'=>array('type'=>'message_create','message_create'=>array('target'=>array('recipient_id'=> '163516804'),'message_data'=>array('text'=>'nessage'))));

$result = $connection->post('direct_messages/events/new',$j1);
echo json_encode($result);

 /*****************************************
 *** Post DM to ID End                  ***
 ******************************************
 **/  
?>
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: $results returns null. Get Followers/friends ids and Post status are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts worked fine after adding "true" parameters

```
$result = $connection->post('direct_messages/events/new',$j1,true);
```